# Command line error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, release

I'm trying to use the `/O2` optimization for my project. I checked that the release configuration was enabled (Solution->Properties->Configuration Properties->Configuration->Release) and set Debug Information Format to `/Zi` but now I don't know what to do for this error.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Starting at Solution->Properties is not helpful.  It appears you have changed the /O2 setting for the Debug configuration, it uses /RTC.  Switch to the Release configuration instead, it already uses /O2 and /Zi so no help is needed.  Use Build > Configuration Manager > Active solution configuration to switch.  And restore the setting.

Comment: If you'll post it as an answer I'll chose it :)

Comment: It's not quite related to the question, but I didn't find the answer in time for myself. It you are using the cmake with Visual Studio generator, then the cmake from some version adds `/O2` flag implicitly to the generated Debug project if didn't found it in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` variable. Basically this variable has used with the `/RTC1` flag already set, so you have to explicitly add the `/Od` flag to it to avoid that behaviour. In my case I did explicitly remove the `/Od` flag from the variable and got the issue.

Comment: As the error says you could switch off either flags and get rid of it.  However, despite them being not set you might still get it (like I did).  This might be because the project properties are overridden by per-file properties; be sure and confirm if optimization level isn't overridden at the `.cpp` level.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The optimization setting Maximize Speed (/O2) is incompatible to the Basic Runtime Checks setting of Code Generation.

To change the settings for Basic Runtime Checks:

Solution -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Basic Runtime Checks

Set it to "Default", and it should work.

[image]

Comment: So, When I change the `BasicRuntimeChecks` options to `Default`, the Debugger ignores the debug-points. In this case, I can't debug the codes line-by-line.